# How to reference to the database that resides on another server in the webconfig file?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new developer and this is my first time to deal with two IIS servers. My company has two servers; Production Server and Testing Server. They are using the testing server for storing /hosting the databases and the Production Server for hosting the applications. All the applications are developed in ASP.NET. Now, for the web-based application that I am developing; I have to put the database in the Testing Server and the application in the Production Server,

**so how can I reference the database in the web.config file?**

What I have in my web.config file now is the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="testConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspTest;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

I have that because the database resides in the same server with the application. Therefore, how will I be able to reference when I put it in the Testing Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your testing server is called `testsrv` and the database resides on the
SQL Server Express instance, you simply change your config to:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="testConnectionString" 
             connectionString="Data Source=testsrv\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspTest;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Or alternatively the IP address of the server !